# Quartz.NET StartNow not working together with WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule

Tags: c#, quartz.net

```
            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                                .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x => x
                                    .WithIntervalInHours(2)
                                    .OnEveryDay()
                                    .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(8, 0))
                                    .EndingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(23, 00)))
                                .StartNow()
                                .Build();
```

The problem with the above code is that `StartNow` is not working. It runs normally but only after 2 hours. I can't run it immediately.

`StartNow` is working with `WithSimpleSchedule` but not with `.WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule` is not what you need. If you specify start time = 8 AM, end time = 11 PM, interval = 2 hours, jobs will be scheduled to run exactly at 8 AM, 10 AM, 12 PM, 2 PM, 4 PM, 6 PM, 8 PM and 10 PM.

As a solution you can create two triggers:

1. If the current time is between 8 AM and 11 PM, create trigger that fires now, now + 2 hours, now + 4 hours and stops today at 11 PM.
2. The second trigger will fire at 8 AM, 10 AM, etc. starting from the next 8 AM time point (today or tomorrow).

Comment: Yes this is the temp solution. I have only 1 job/trigger with `WithSimpleSchedule` and i check if it is between 8-11.